# How to prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}f(\frac{1}{x})$?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm stuck at this problem. I tried to write down the hypothesis but it eludes me how we can use them to obtain the thesis.

Suppose that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=L$, a real number.
By definition that means that for any fixed $\epsilon$ there exists a $g$ such that if $x>g$ then $L-\epsilon<f(x)<L+\epsilon$.

But now, how can I work on $f(x)$ in such a way to obtain some expression for $f(\frac{1}{x})$?

Comment: "there exis a g" What is g? Also if $x\to +\infty$ then changing to $1/x$ should translate to $x\to 0+$.

Comment: A @Gary pointed out, the current formulation cannot be proven. You have to explicitly write the limit for $x \to 0+$ and not a general $x \to 0$, which includes $x \to 0-$.

Comment: Note that my solution is not correct please unaccept it so I can delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Prove:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L \implies \lim_{x \to 0^+} f(1/x) = L. \tag1 $$

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(1/x) = L \implies \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L. \tag2 $$

---

$\underline{\text{Proof of (1)}}$

$\forall \epsilon > 0, ~\exists y > 0,~$ such that 
$x > y \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon.$

Take $\delta = (1/y) \implies \delta > 0$. 
Then, $0 < x < \delta \implies (1/x) > y \implies |f(1/x) - L| < \epsilon.$

---

$\underline{\text{Proof of (2)}}$

$\forall \epsilon > 0, ~\exists \delta > 0,~$ such that 
$0 < x < \delta \implies |f(1/x) - L| < \epsilon.$

Take $g = (1/\delta) \implies g > 0$. 
Then, $x > g \implies 0 < (1/x) < \delta \implies 
\displaystyle \left|f\left(\frac{1}{1/x}\right) - L\right| < \epsilon.$

Since $\displaystyle \left(\frac{1}{1/x}\right) = (x)$, you have that 
$x > g \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon.$